# How Get data and Responce data in android by Http?

Tags: c#, java, android, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I want send data from android  to website asp.net  by Http,
but  website in my computer in visual studio 2010 , how  send data from mobile to website by Http.
Note : i translate data by wireless network

please Give me Tutorial about how connection between mobile and  visual studio(setting mobile and   visual studio  ) .
and Example code  in java how send data from mobile and receive  in website asp.net.

Comment: Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043587/android-post-request-for-aspx

Comment: this code is "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043587/android-post-request-for-aspx" is right no error ,if right how receive in asp.net and what is setting website (Port , and IP ).

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the code example if I would communicate with server**

```
// this method takes URL as input and returns JSON data 
//parent class name is "NewWebHelper.java"

public String getResult(String url) {

        Log.v(TAG, "Final Requsting URL is : :"+url);

        String line = "";
        String responseJsonData = null;

        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String x = "";
            URL httpurl = new URL(url);
            URLConnection  tc= httpurl.openConnection();   

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                              new InputStreamReader(tc.getInputStream()));

            if(in !=null){
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
                x = sb.toString();
            }
            responseJsonData = new String(x);

            }
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException uh){            
            Log.v("NewWebHelper", "Unknown host :");
            uh.printStackTrace();
        }
       catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           Log.v("NewWebHelper", "FileNotFoundException :");
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v("NewWebHelper", "IOException :");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      catch (Exception e) {
          Log.v("NewWebHelper", "Exception :");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responseJsonData;
    }
```

---

Let me know if you have any trouble regrading this.

Comment: Thanks , but i want code "send" data from mobile to website by http not in json return .